# Symfony Zend Lucene Search Multiple Tables

Tags: zend-framework, search, symfony1, lucene, symfony-1.4

I have a Symfony project and I used Zend Lucene Search framework to integrate a search on the site. It works beautifully but it's limited to searching 1 table.

I need my users to be able to search the whole site (8 select tables) and return the results all together. Each table has the same fields indexed. This is the code that specifies the table and calls the query.

Is there a way to make it look through all 8 tables for results?

```
public function getForLuceneQuery($query)
{
  $hits = self::getLuceneIndex()->find($query);

  $pks = array();
  foreach ($hits as $hit)
  {
    $pks[] = $hit->pk;
  }

  if (empty($pks))
  {
    return array();
  }
  $alltables = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Car');
  $q = $alltables->createQuery('j')
     ->whereIn('j.token', $pks)
     ->orderBy('j.endtime ASC')
     ->andwhere('j.endtime > ?', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()))
     ->andWhere('j.activated = ?', '1')
     ->limit(21);

  return $q->execute();
}
```

To give a bit of background on the 8 tables, they are all basically similar.   They all have title, make, model, etc so I need to run a single query on all of them and return all results (regardless of which table it is in) in Ascending order.  The Doctrine_core::getTable command doesn't seem to like multiple tables or even arrays (unless I'm not doing it right).  Thanks!

UPDATE (WORKING):

Here is the updated code.  This is what I have in the `SearchTable.class.php` file:

```
public function getForLuceneQuery($query)
{
  // sort search result by end time
  $hits = self::getLuceneIndex()->find(
    $query, 'endtime', SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_ASC
  );

  $result = array(
    'index' => $hits,
    'database' => array(),
  );

  // group search result by class
  foreach ($hits as $hit)
  {
    if (!isset($result['database'][$hit->class]))
    {
      $result['database'][$hit->class] = array();
    }

    $result['database'][$hit->class][] = $hit->pk;
  }

  // replace primary keys with real results
  foreach ($result['database'] as $class => $pks)
  {
    $result['database'][$class] = Doctrine_Query::create()
      // important to INDEXBY the same field as $hit->pk
      ->from($class . ' j INDEXBY j.token')
      ->whereIn('j.token', $pks)
      ->orderBy('j.endtime ASC')
      ->andwhere('j.endtime > ?', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()))
      ->andWhere('j.activated = ?', '1')
      ->limit(21)
      ->execute();

  }

  return $result;
}
```

Here is what I have in the `actions.class.php` file for the Search Module:

```
public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->forwardUnless($query = $request->getParameter('query'), 'home', 'index');

    $this->results = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Search') 
      ->getForLuceneQuery($query);

  }
```

And finally this is my template file `indexSuccess.php`  I have simplified it so it's easier to understand.  My `indexSuccess.php` is more complicated but now that I can call the values, I can customize it further.

```
  <div class="product_list"
  <ul>
    <?php foreach ($results['index'] as $hit): ?>
      <li class="item">
      <?php if (isset($results['database'][$hit->class][$hit->pk])) ?>
        <span class="title">
            <?php echo $results['database'][$hit->class][$hit->pk]->getTitle() ?>
        </span>
      </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

This works beautifully.  I was able to customize it by calling each of the fields in the search results and it works perfect.   I added an item to each of the tables with the same title and the search result pulled them all.   Thank you so much!

Comment: I think it can't be done with 1 query. You should store model class names in the index and then after a search you can group matched primary keys to an array like `array('model class name' => array(pk))` and execute a query on each table that has matches. Ordering can be done when querying the index and when display the result. You can iterate over the original result set and pick the appropriate record from the result of the queries. But I have no idea how pagination can be done. Alternatively you can store all data you need to display in the index, and use only that without querying the db.

Comment: Can I perform multiple queries (one on each table), then join the results, sort them in ascending order, and then display it?  I'm not sure what the code would look like for this.   Sorry, I am a bit new to Symfony.  Thanks.

Comment: Of course you can marge and short the result into one `Doctrine_Collection` but I think that would be too much overhead. I've just posted my previous idea as an answer and added some code to it.

Comment: For your last error, try: `$result->getRawValue()->gettitle()`

Comment: With that one I get `Fatal error: Call to a member function gettitle() on a non-object`

Comment: If it helps, I changed the line to `<?php echo $result ?>` just to see if it will output the raw data but then I got this error `Catchable fatal error: Object of class sfOutputEscaperArrayDecorator could not be converted to string`

Comment: As I write in the example you should iterate over `$result['index']` (in your case `$results['index']`) not only just `$results` as it's an array containing the search results from lucene and the actual result objects from doctrine. In the `foreach` you can reach the actual doctrine records as I did (don't forget the `isset` part), and should call `$result['database'][$hit->class][$hit->pk]->getTitle()`. In this case every record object in the result set should have a `getTitle()` method, if it's not the case you should alter the rendering based on object type.

Comment: I have updated my original question with the updated code.   I'm not sure how I missed that second part to your answer, but alas, you are awesome.   You have no idea how grateful I am for your help.   It works beautifully.  Thanks again!!

Comment: I have run into a small problem and I'm hoping you can still help if you can.   It doesn't seem to sort or limit the results.   Even though there is a SORT and a LIMIT in the query, doesn't matter what I set (ASC, DESC, etc) it still displays in the order in which they were indexed.  I need to be able to sort all the results differently depending on which page I'm displaying.   Also, It seems to query ALL items that match the query instead of limiting it to the top 21 as specified in the query. I'm thinking this is because the query runs each time the loop comes back around. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I'll try to give you some hint, with code :)

First of all you should add these fields to the index:

```
$doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Keyword('class', get_class($record)));
$doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnIndexed('endtime', strtotime($record->get('endtime'))));
```

Than you should use these new fields:

```
public function getForLuceneQuery($query)
{
  // sort search result by end time
  $hits = self::getLuceneIndex()->find(
    $query, 'endtime', SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_ASC
  );

  $result = array(
    'index' => $hits,
    'database' => array(),
  );

  // group search result by class
  foreach ($hits as $hit)
  {
    if (!isset($result['database'][$hit->class]))
    {
      $result['database'][$hit->class] = array();
    }

    $result['database'][$hit->class][] = $hit->pk;
  }

  // replace primary keys with real results
  foreach ($result['database'] as $class => $pks)
  {
    $result['database'][$class] = Doctrine_Query::create()
      // important to INDEXBY the same field as $hit->pk
      ->from($class . ' j INDEXBY j.token')
      ->whereIn('j.token', $pks)
      ->orderBy('j.endtime ASC')
      ->andwhere('j.endtime > ?', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()))
      ->andWhere('j.activated = ?', '1')
      ->limit(21)
      ->execute();

    // if you want different query per table
    // you should call a function which executes the query
    //
    // if (!method_exists($table = Doctrine_Core::getTable($class), 'getLuceneSearchResult'))
    // {
    //   throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('"%s::%s" have to be exists to get the search results.', get_class($table), 'getLuceneSearchResult'));
    // }
    //
    // $results[$class] = call_user_func(array($table, 'getLuceneSearchResult'), $pks);
  }

  return $result;
}
```

After that in the template you should iterate over `$result['index']` and display results from `$result['database']`

```
foreach ($result['index'] as $hit)
{
  if (isset($result['database'][$hit->class][$hit->pk]))
  {
    echo $result['database'][$hit->class][$hit->pk];
  }
}
```

---

And there are same alternate (maybe better) solutions that I can think of:

Alternate solution #1:

You can store data in the index and this data will be accessible in the search result. If you not need too much data when displaying the results and can update the index frequently I think this is a good option. This way you can use pagination and no SQL queries needed at all.

```
$doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('title', $content->get('title')));
...
$hit->title;
```

Alternate solution #2:

As you wrote, your tables are very similar, so you maybe could use [column aggregation inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/inheritance.html#column-aggregation). In this way all data stored in one table so you can query them all together and can order and paginate as you want.

Comment: I think I like the Alternate solution #1 better.   The less overhead the better.  How do I call the values from the template though.   Do I assign each to a variable?  I tried calling $hit->title; from the template and it says variable "hit" was not defined.   Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: You should query the index in an action like `$this->hits = YourCustomClass::getLuceneIndex($query, ...);` and in this case `$this->hits` will be accessible in templates as `$hits`. It is an array of `Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_QueryHit` objects, you should iterate over this array in a template `foreach ($hits as $hit) { echo $hit->title; }`

Comment: I'm sorry, I realized that alternate solution #1 indexes things that I don't want searchable.  I would like to keep the index as clean as possible, so I attempted your original answer.  In doing so, it seems that the query runs ok but when I call `$result->getPicture1()` in the template and it says `Fatal error: Call to undefined method sfOutputEscaperArrayDecorator::getpicture1()`  Which is one of the unindexed values in my table.  I can update my original question with code if you need to see it.

Comment: I think it's a Doctrine issue, try call `$result->getPicture_1()` or `$result->get('picture_1')`. If not works please updated your question with the relevant code of the action and the template.

Comment: Just updated my original question with the updated code.  Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.  :)